# Can't read csv file in same directory

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a problem with a Pandas df read_csv command, when I use

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Johnn\\Desktop\\Stock Picker\\Find Tickercode\\path.csv')
```

it works, and when I use

```
df = pd.read_csv('path.csv')
```

it dosent, but the csv file is in tha same directory as the py file, så I dont understand why

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'path.csv' does not exist: b'path.csv
```

Can anybody please explain it for me.
The py script is located in

```
C:\Users\Johnn\Desktop\Stock Picker\Find Tickercode\path.csv
```

And my editor is Atom

Comment: where are you running the .py file from?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems not, rather check again - `is in tha same directory as the py file,`

Comment: Python is not running in the same directory as your CSV file resides. Try running Python from that directory.

Comment: your csv file and python file need to be in same folder then your second solution will work

Comment: yes you were all right but to me it is just a little strange that if you run the program from Atom then it does not work but if you run it from CMD it works. Thangs a lot

Comment: In Python, you can always learn about your current working directory by issuing: os.getcwd()

Comment: See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40627075/how-do-i-get-current-working-directory-in-atom