# I can't seem to open an image using pygame

Tags: python, windows, image, pygame

I am a newbie in Python following a tutorial online for making an AI learn to play Flappy bird. My problem is that I can't seem to load the images for the game that I have saved in a folder using this syntax:

```
BIRD_IMGS = 
[pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","bird1.png"))),
 pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","bird2.png"))),
 pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join("imgs","bird3.png")))]
```

The error I get is the following:

> pygame.error: Couldn't open imgs\bird1.png

My paths are:

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Web Development\Python\Flappy_Bird_AI\master.py
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Web Development\Python\Flappy_Bird_AI\imgs\bird1.png
```

for the code and image, respectively.

Anyone know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pygame.error: Couldn't open image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684198/pygame-error-couldnt-open-image)

Comment: Hardly.. All I got from that was that I need to switch from VScode, also I don't want to use absolute paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably running your script from a different working directory than the one that has the image.

You can do the following to get the absolute path dynamically within your script

```
DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
IMGS_DIR = os.path.join(DIR, "imgs")

BIRD_IMGS = [pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(IMGS_DIR,"bird1.png"))),
 pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(IMGS_DIR,"bird2.png"))),
 pygame.transform.scale2x(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(IMGS_DIR,"bird3.png")))]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot dude, works like a charm, directories and paths are a bit complex for my level ;)