# Can't Open image files in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to write a game in VS Code, but whenever I try to open an image using:

hero.image = pygame.image.load("Character.jpeg")
(The images are in the game folder)

I get varied error messages. One computer it says "pygame.error: Couldn't open Character.png" and on another, it says something to do with incorrect sRGB profile. I have tried running the program on different computers, tried it with different images in different image formats, .gif, .png, and .jpeg.

Comment: try once by changing it to absolute path. Also you can refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32684198/cannot-open-images-with-pygame-in-atom

Comment: "(The images are in the game folder)" Does your program run "in the game folder" as well? *Check; do not assume*.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Comment: sRGB is just a warning, its not an error. It won't affect your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your answers, it turns out the problem was that the folder was stored on a cloud location, and the computer cannot do it from there. The way I fixed it was making a copy of the image on the actual PC, I didn't need to actually use that version of the image, but as long as it is there the program works.